# How to access variable of parent process in C?

Tags: c, linux, process

There is one var named "users" in one process and the process fork some child processes, I want know how could these child processes access the "users" variable ?

BTW:
The variable will be modified by parent process in runtime

Comment: Would you want to share the variable among the processes or just having copies is fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use shared memory. You will need [to open](http://linux.die.net/man/3/shm_open) a file, use [this](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ftruncate) to set the length (probably sizeof(*var)), [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) it. Do this before the fork. After you are finished [unmap it](http://linux.die.net/man/2/munmap), [close the file](http://linux.die.net/man/2/close), and [unlink](http://linux.die.net/man/3/shm_unlink) the shared file.

```
void *mem;
int shm_fd;
shm_fd = shm_open("file", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0644);
ftruncate(shm_fd, sizeof(int));
mem = mmap(0, sizeof(int), PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
/* fork it, use it */
munmap(mem, sizeof(int));
close(shm_fd);
shm_unlink("file");
```

Answer (score 0):

Linux uses mechanism called copy-on-write. That basically means, that as long as variable is not modified parent and new process are sharing one variable. But before variable is modified it is copied and new process uses copy. It is done for performance reasons and technique is called lazy optimization. You can set your variable as static, then you can directly access it.

Comment: The variable will be modified by parent process

Answer (score 0):

Forking in C will create a child process which has all the copies of parent variables.
If you simply want that variable.then you can use the copy of that anyhow which was created by fork.
If you want to share that variable's you can go for implementing IPC mechanisms.
you can see a guide good for using IPC mechanisms [here](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/)